# Space of divergence-free vector fields on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, divergence-operator

Let $(M,h)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold of dimension $d\geq 1$ with smooth metric. Set $X:=\{A=  \mbox{smooth vector field s.t. } div_h A=0 \}$.

Then $X$ is an infinite dimensional vector space.
How to prove this?

Comment: I am aware of the question

[How to prove the space of divergence-free vector fields on a manifold is infinite dimensional?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2624671/how-to-prove-the-space-of-divergence-free-vector-fields-on-a-manifold-is-infinit/2624779)

but the proof therein does not convince me completely: I cannot see why one should be able to write locally $dV_h= dx^1\cdots dx^d$

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257724/any-volume-form-on-a-smooth-n-dimensional-manifold-is-locally-a-pullback-of-th